# Method for calculating the stopping distance using only integers

Tags: computational-physics

I am trying to find how much an engine would turn until it stops accelerating with an acceleration of $a = A \sin^2(x)$.

**Acceleration**

[image: Acceleration]

Integrating the acceleration I get velocity $v = A(x/2 - \sin(2x)/4) $

Integrating the velocity, I get the distance $d = A(x^2/4 - \cos^2(x)/4) $

**Velocity and distance**

[image]

Now, I need to do this calculation on a microcontroller, without using floating point and with a sine look-up table which is basically a $2048\sin(x\pi/512)$ function.

How can I find the distance correctly using the sine look up table? Or what other way could I use?

Comment: Is the question just how to obtain a cosine function from your sine lookup table? The two are related by a shift of $\pi/2$ (or an offset of `256` in the case of your table)....

Comment: The problem is if i integrate the lookup function as in **Integrate((2048 sin(x Pi/512))^2)** the results deviate from the original curve, I get a sinusoidal error in distance. 
If i try to change the sine and cosines to the look-up versions i get a sinusoidal error in velocity curve.
Is this somewhat understandable?

Comment: Why do you need to integrate your lookup table when you have a closed form equation for everything. You probably need to edit your question to clarify what you're asking. Or spend some more time thinking about this exercise and trying things out.